# Cannot redeclare class Drush error

Tags: 8, drush

When I go to my site on command line and run a drush command I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Drush in /var/www/xmd8/www/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush.php on line 36
```

If I run `which drush` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/drush
```

I have the [Lightning](https://github.com/acquia/lightning) Distribution installed via composer and they are adding Drush.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Drush version 9.0-dev installed which was causing issues.  I downgraded to 8.0.5 and this problem went away.  Thanks @greg_1_anderson for giving me the idea.

Comment: It is probably overly ambitious of Lightning to require Drush 9; this version is still in early development. I'd recommend Drush 8 for most folks' global Drush as well.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Drush are you using?  Recent versions of Drush will notice that there is a copy of Drush included in your Drupal site, and will redispatch (exec) to use it instead.  If you are using an old, unsupported version of Drush (e.g. Drush 6 or earlier), then it will not do this, and the error you see above would be the likely result.

Comment: Drush Version   :  9.0-dev